# Login failing but after many attempts, view is segued to different view

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create login functionality for my app using SQLite as my database. I'm using the right username and password but keep getting an error from SQLite saying an unknown error occurred. After many attempts of repeatedly pressing the login button, I'm able to bypass the login screen.

Here is my login button functionality

```
var db: OpaquePointer?
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!

    //the defaultvalues to store user data
    let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    @IBAction func Login(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //creating a statement
        var stmt: OpaquePointer?

        //the insert query
        let queryString = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE username = ? AND password = ? "

        //preparing the query
        if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        //binding the parameters
        if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, username.text!, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }
        if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, password.text!, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        //executing the query
        if sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW {
            let TableView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableView") as! TableView
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(TableView, animated: true)
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("Login Failed: \(errmsg)")
            self.labelMessage.text = "Invalid username or password"
            return
        }
    }
```

db setup in viewcontroller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("sDB.sqlite")
    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }
    if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, f_name TEXT, l_name TEXT, password TEXT)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the values of the two strings when the login passes? Are you accidentally manipulating the saved values or setting the input values to the saved ones?

Comment: Yes I looked at the values and they don't seem to get manipulated.

Comment: So the textFields' text are not equal to saved strings but the query sees them equal?

Comment: So originally the problem was that after many touches on the login button, it would bypass the conditions and go on to the next screen. I think I'm not getting the text from the fields properly because i keep getting an 'unknown error' when passing the text from the fields onto the query.